# Does CoreData allow object graph loops? (Strange error)

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I've been having a strange problem with CoreData for a while now. This will be a lenghty question, so bear with me...

I have two Entites, call them A and B. B might be both creator and updater of several A's. A must have a B as creator, and may or may not have a B as updater. (Required and optional relationships.)

B might have both created and updated zero or more A's.

[image: With inverse relationships]

The above is the data model I built. (I don't really *need* the inverse relationship from B to A, but CoreData gives me compile time warnings otherwise.)

**EDIT**

Here are the relevant parts of the ManagedObject subclasses:

A.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) B * creator;
@property (nonatomic, retain) B * updater;
```

A.m

```
@dynamic creator;
@dynamic updater;
```

B.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet * created;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet * updated;
```

B.m

```
@dynamic updated;
@dynamic created;

- (void)addUpdatedObject:(A *)value { NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet
alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1]; [self
willChangeValueForKey:@"updated"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
usingObjects:changedObjects]; [[self
primitiveValueForKey:@"updated"] addObject:value]; [self
didChangeValueForKey:@"updated"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
usingObjects:changedObjects]; [changedObjects release]; }

- (void)removeUpdatedObject:(A *)value { NSSet *changedObjects =
[[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1]; [self
willChangeValueForKey:@"updated"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
usingObjects:changedObjects]; [[self
primitiveValueForKey:@"updated"] removeObject:value]; [self
didChangeValueForKey:@"updated"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
usingObjects:changedObjects]; [changedObjects release]; }

- (void)addUpdated:(NSSet *)value { [self
willChangeValueForKey:@"updated"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
[[self primitiveValueForKey:@"updated"] unionSet:value]; [self
didChangeValueForKey:@"updated"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value]; }

- (void)removeUpdated:(NSSet *)value { [self
willChangeValueForKey:@"updated"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
[[self primitiveValueForKey:@"updated"] minusSet:value]; [self
didChangeValueForKey:@"updated"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value]; }

- (void)addCreatedObject:(A *)value { NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet
alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1]; [self
willChangeValueForKey:@"created"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
usingObjects:changedObjects]; [[self
primitiveValueForKey:@"created"] addObject:value]; [self
didChangeValueForKey:@"created"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation
usingObjects:changedObjects]; [changedObjects release]; }

- (void)removeCreatedObject:(A *)value { NSSet *changedObjects =
[[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1]; [self
willChangeValueForKey:@"created"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
usingObjects:changedObjects]; [[self
primitiveValueForKey:@"created"] removeObject:value]; [self
didChangeValueForKey:@"created"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation
usingObjects:changedObjects]; [changedObjects release]; }

- (void)addCreated:(NSSet *)value { [self
willChangeValueForKey:@"created"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
[[self primitiveValueForKey:@"created"] unionSet:value]; [self
didChangeValueForKey:@"created"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value]; }

- (void)removeCreated:(NSSet *)value { [self
willChangeValueForKey:@"created"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
[[self primitiveValueForKey:@"created"] minusSet:value]; [self
didChangeValueForKey:@"created"
withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value]; }
```

**END EDIT**

When I create a new A with a B as creator, everything is fine (when using inverse relationships). However, when I update that same A later, using the same B as creator, i get the following crash:

```
2011-05-05 13:17:40.885 myapp[27033:207] -[NSCFNumber count]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d14eb0

2011-05-05 13:17:40.887 myapp[27033:207] *** Terminating app due to
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber
count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
0x5d14eb0'

*** Call stack at first throw: ( 

0 CoreFoundation 0x014065a9
__exceptionPreprocess + 185


    1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0155a313 objc_exception_throw + 44

    2 CoreFoundation 0x014080bb -[NSObject(NSObject)
    doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187

    3 CoreFoundation 0x01377966 ___forwarding___ + 966

    4 CoreFoundation 0x01377522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50

    5 CoreFoundation 0x013b7c3b -[NSSet intersectsSet:] + 59

    6 Foundation 0x00c3f4fb NSKeyValueWillChangeBySetMutation +
    422

    7 Foundation 0x00c0416d NSKeyValueWillChange + 400

    8 Foundation 0x00c3f34d
    -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification)
    willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:] + 315

    9 CoreData 0x01172bd0 -[NSManagedObject
    willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:] + 112

    10 myapp 0x0004fd48 -[B addUpdatedObject:] + 168

    11 CoreData 0x011729f2 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods)
    _includeObject:intoPropertyWithKey:andIndex:] + 98

    12 CoreData 0x01169301 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods)
    _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 497

    13 Foundation 0x00c051e4 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 361

    14 Foundation 0x00c04ca6 NSKeyValueDidChange + 384

    15 Foundation 0x00beb3e2
    -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification)
    didChangeValueForKey:] + 123

    16 CoreData 0x01166adb
    _PF_ManagedObject_DidChangeValueForKeyIndex + 171

    17 CoreData 0x01165de9 _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 313

    18 CoreData 0x01173997 _svfk_11 + 39
```

(Yes, *B* has the method `addUpdatedObject`defined.)

For further background, the list of A:s are shown in a `UITableView` backed by a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

The strangest thing is, IMHO, that it's perfectly possible to add a new A (with B as creator) with the inverse relationship without it leading to a crash, while adding the same B as updater to that same A leads to a crash.

However, when I remove the inverse relationships, everything works as expected.

[image: Without inverse relationships]

I can add the same B as A:s creator and updater without any problems, and the app works as it should, except for the build-time warnings from CoreData:

```
A.creator should have an inverse
A.updater should have an inverse
```

So, is there any CoreData guru out there that can explain why the first case breaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not supposed to be able to set up a double relationship. Xcode 3.x and earlier wouldn't even allow you to create a model with double relationships (Just checking now with Xcode 4, looks like it will let you do so without warning. Not a good idea.)

Double relationships are strongly not recommended because they poise serious risk to graph integrity e.g. delete rules, what happens if you have a rule of `delete` on one relationship and `deny` on the other? I think graphs with double relationships are just trainwrecks waiting to happen.

More importantly, I've never see a situation in which such a data model was truly needed. Usually, a better data model design will obviate the apparent need for such a dangerous setup. In this case, I think you need to insert entities to model the actual relationships themselves because the relationships actually have behaviors or sorts:

```
A{
  creator<-->Creation.a
  updater<-->Update.a
}

B{
  creations<-->>Creation.b
  updates<-->>Update.b
}

Creation{
  a<-->A.creator
  b<-->>B.cretions
}

Update{
  a<-->A.updater
  b<<-->B.updates
}
```

This also lets you easily model things like the date of an update just by adding an attribute to the `Update` entity.

Comment: Ah, that was about what I've thought all along, then. Time for a bug report to Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the ManagedObject subclasses again for both entities after changing the model (by adding the inverses)?

If you didn't, the model may try to add inverse references to an object which is not prepared to accept them.

Comment: Yes, I did, but it didn't help. I tried build->clean a couple of times too, in case there was anything weird going on, like the model not updating...

Comment: Did you step through your code to see if it is actually the call adding one entity to another which causes the crash? One more thing..: If it wasn't for the "works-one-way-but-not-the-other"-thing, I'd think this could be memory management related (because of the count message being sent to a "random" object). Have you tried turning zombies on, yet?

Comment: I did run it with zombies on for a while, yes. Might have turned it off again. Will have to try that, and single-stepping, again.

Comment: The `count` thing makes me think that it could be something about the nsfetchedresultscontroller that gives rise to the crash. But my main hunch is that it has something to do with recursion. When adding an inverse to one object, there is a change to the other, which is connected back again to the first object via a different relationship. Dunno.